# Showing that the sequence $z^n$ is normally but not uniformly convergent

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I was able to show that $z^n$ is normally convergent on the unit disk centred at the origin, but I am not sure how to show that it is not uniformly convergent on the unit disk centred at the origin.  I've read in a few places that this is true, but I have not seen a proof.

My first idea was to fix an $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon=1/2$.  Then $|z^n|<1/2$.  However, I haven't been able to get this to work out.

Comment: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185876/why-is-this-sequence-of-functions-not-uniformly-convergent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185876/why-is-this-sequence-of-functions-not-uniformly-convergent) this might help

Comment: It’s not true. For $n ∈ ℕ$, choose $z = \sqrt[n]{2/3}$, then $|z^n - 0 |= 2/3 > ε$.

Comment: @happymath Good find. Vote to close this question and cite the reason "duplicate" if you think this question is a duplicate of the one you found.

Comment: Nevertheless, why is this downvoted? Okay, it’s a duplicate. But why is this downvoted?

Comment: @5xum i do not know how to vote to close

Comment: @happymath [You can’t](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (yet).

Comment: @k.stm then i guess only 5xum can do it

Answer (score 0):

HINT: if $(f_n)_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions, what can you say about its limit if the sequence converges uniformly?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The "tail" of the series (when you truncate immediately after the $z^{n-1}$ term) is equal to $\frac{z^n}{1-z}$. For $z$ with $|z|\lt 1$ but fairly close to $1$, this has norm $\gt \frac{1}{2}|z|^n$. Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, is there an $N$ **independent of** $|z|$ such that $\frac{1}{2}|z|^n\lt \epsilon$ for all $n\gt N$ and all $|z|\lt 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Normal convergence means it should have a subsequence which converges uniformly on compact subsets.  Here our domain is the unit disk.  If you take a compact set $K\subset\mathbb{D}$ then we can find a closed disk $B[0, r]$ where $0<r<1$ such that $K\subset B[0, r]$. Now, if we consider the original sequence on $K$, then we have $\sup_{z\in K}|z|^n \leq r^n$, which goes to zero. Hence the given sequence converges normally in $\mathbb{D}$. As $\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}}|z|^n = 1$ which does not goes to zero, the sequence does not converge uniformly in
$\mathbb{D}$.