# Why is $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $f_n :[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=x^n$ not uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

If I choose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(1)=1$ and otherwise $f(x)=0$ then $||f_n-f||_{[0,1]}\rightarrow0$ therefore it is uniformly convergent and because it is uniformly convergent $f$ would have to be continuous but it is not, where is the mistake?

Comment: Since $\lim_n f_n$ is not continuous, it cannot be the uniform limit of any sequence of continuous functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not uniformly convergent. For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ you can choose $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2}}$ and get $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{2}$. So it doesn't matter how far you go in the sequence, the distance will never be less than $\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$.